# How to get 'Last BIOS time' from CLI

Tags: windows

I'd like to get `Last BIOS time` on task manager from CLI with Win10.
The Last BIOS time is shown at 'startup' tab of Task Manager.
As you can see like below:

[image]

I've googled and the closest answer I found is https://superuser.com/a/644725/393796 , however, I still can't get the specific value of the time which should be 12.9 seconds in above scenario.

Answer (score 0):

No command to get that. You could use GetFirmwareEnvironmentVariable api to get that. It seems to get the same data equal to the text in startup page of task manager.

It provided by https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/7c837a5a-5b9e-4908-9e04-562fb0d4f815/get-last-bios-time-in-windows10?forum=win10itprohardware